# What's the best way to visually compare codec compression?

Tags: compression

Maybe I'm mistaken, but a long while ago I seem to have read an article about comparing videos encoded by different codecs.

Basically what I think what was done, was to put them together in a timeline - and by use of some effects - "null" them so you could only see the difference.

Now that I'm writing it down, I'm not so sure anymore - but I just wanted to check if someone knows a way to efficiently compare codec compressions.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of 2 perspectives: industrial and recreational.

Industrial: visual examination is super expensive, you may take a look of how Netflix do the comparison https://netflixtechblog.com/performance-comparison-of-video-coding-standards-an-adaptive-streaming-perspective-d45d0183ca95

Recreational: you may check out youtube with codec comparison e.g.

or doom9

Hope this answers your questions.

Comment: I wouldn't say objective codec testing has to be super expensive. PSNR, SSIM, and VMAF are all freely available (as in beer and as in speech) in ffmpeg. Sure, if you want to use a commercial codec analysis system, like [Interra Vega](https://www.interrasystems.com/vega-analyzer.php), you'll need the budget to support it.

Comment: Expensive, in my answer, refer to human involvement since workforce and working hour are limited; Better solution is automation.